# colspan not working when position is fix

Tags: html

I have this html table

```
<td colspan="1" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">SKILL LEVEL</td>
```

But upon inserting position : fixed

```
<td colspan="1" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;position:fixed">SKILL LEVEL</td>
```

the colspan is not working.

[image]

I just want Skill Level, Monthly and Yearly to be fixed on top while scrolling down.

Here is what happen when i've added the position:fixed
[image]

Comment: I think a little more code is helpful. What is the structure of your code?

Comment: colspan=1? do you understand what it is for or how to use it?